# SFML Network Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, sfml

I need to create a thread to run the Networking portion of my game. I would prefer to use SFML threads as my compiler doesn't yet support C++11 threads. However the class which contains the thread is created with `make_shared()`. Here is the code:

Game.cpp (not all the code just the declaration of GameScreen)

```
std::shared_ptr<Screen> Game::screen = std::make_shared<GameScreen>();
```

Screen is just a base class containing pure virtual functions. You should be able to figure out which ones are virtual based off the override keywords.

GameScreen.h

```
#ifndef GAMESCREEN_H
#define GAMESCREEN_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "Events.h"
#include "Screen.h"
#include "Map.h"
#include "Network.h"

class GameScreen : public Screen
{
public:
    GameScreen();

    void handleInput(sf::RenderWindow&) override;
    void update(sf::RenderWindow&, sf::View&) override;
    void render(sf::RenderWindow&) override;


private:
    Map m_map;
    Network network;
    Events eventManager;

    sf::Thread networkThread;
};

#endif // GAMESCREEN_H
```

GameScreen.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#include "GameScreen.h"
#include "Game.h"


GameScreen::GameScreen()
: networkThread(network.receive(eventManager))
{
    network.Connect();
}

void GameScreen::handleInput(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    /*Code*/
}

void GameScreen::update(sf::RenderWindow& window, sf::View& view)
{
    /*Code*/
}

void GameScreen::render(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    /*Code*/
}
```

Network.cpp (receive function only)

```
void Network::Recieve(Events& eManager)
{
    sf::Packet m_rPacket;
    m_socket.receive(m_rPacket, m_serverIP, port);
    m_rPacket >> /*Data*/
    eManager.addEvent(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Uh, why can't the method reference [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_this_pointer.htm)???  And, if you want to reference the class instance ... *THEN WHY ARE YOU MAKING IT STATIC?!?*

Comment: I need to make it static otherwise the SFML threads don't work properly

Comment: The SFML `thread` class can be given a non-static class method.

Comment: @Cronnoc: I'm hearing an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=542341) here.  Specifically: 1) If you want to pass a "this" reference to a method, you can do it.  2) However, in almost call cases, the best solution is to make the method non-stack and simply use the "built in" "this" reference.  3) You do *NOT* need to make the method "static" just to accomodate SFML threads.  See the other responses.  4) If you still have questions/problems getting your non-static method working correctly, please update your post with details.

Comment: @paulsm4 Ok, I will rewrite my question asking about the problem not my thought up solution.

Comment: Its helpful to actually ask a question too. Its not at all clear what you want answered.

Comment: hopefully a moderator will delete this soon

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` in the constructor's initialization list:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
    : AClass(&MyFunction(*this))
{
    /*do stuff*/
}
```

However, this doesn't make sense in your example, because you are trying to pass a pointer to `MyFunction` (or its non-existent return value) to `AClass()`, and you can't quality a pointer with parameters.  You can only pass parameters to `MyFunction()` when actually **calling** `MyFunction()`.  Are you sure you don't actually mean something more like this instead:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
    : AClass()
{
    /*do stuff*/
    MyFunction(*this);
}
```

Without seeing what `AClass()` actually is, or what it expects as input, it is difficult to know for sure what you are trying to do.

**Update** clearly you have not read the [SFML documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Thread.php) or [SFML Tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/system-thread.php) on threading.  The `Thread` constructor takes a pointer to a function/method as one input parameter, and an optional input value for the function/method as a separate parameter.  Try this instead:

```
class MyClass : public sf::Thread
{
private:
    static void MyFunction(MyClass &cls);
public:
    MyClass();
};
```

```
MyClass::MyClass()
    : sf::Thread(&MyClass::MyFunction, *this)
{
    /*do stuff*/
}

void MyClass::MyFunction(MyClass &cls)
{
    /*do stuff with 'cls'*/
}
```

Or this, as you *can* use a non-static class method with an SFML thread:

```
class MyClass : public sf::Thread
{
private:
    void MyFunction();

public:
    MyClass();
};

MyClass::MyClass()
    : sf::Thread(&MyClass::MyFunction, *this)
{
    /*do stuff*/
}

void MyClass::MyFunction()
{
    /*do stuff with 'this'*/
}
```

**Update**: based on your new code, you are still not even close to constructing the `sf::Thread` object correctly (did you read the documentation/tutorial I linked to?).  Also, your thread needs access to multiple objects owned by `GameScreen`, so you can't pass them all to the `sf::Thread` constructor.  You need to do something more like this instead:

```
class GameScreen : public Screen
{
public:
    GameScreen();

    ...

private:
    ...
    Network network;
    Events eventManager;

    sf::Thread networkThread;
    void networkThreadFunc();
};
```

```
GameScreen::GameScreen()
    : networkThread(&GameScreen::networkThreadFunc, *this)
{
    network.Connect();
}

void GameScreen::networkThreadFunc()
{
    network.Receive(eventManager);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i'll edit the question because it is a SFML threading class, I just wanted to make the question as general as I could

Comment: I have re-written the question so this answer may no longer be relevant.

Comment: Then you should have closed/deleted this question and posted a new one.

Comment: Ok, i'm still new to stack exchange

Comment: Even after your re-write, the root issue is still the same.  You are not constructing `sf::Thread` correctly. I have updated my answer.